# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'error' roundcube plugin

Tags: php, roundcube, vtigercrm

getting an error PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'error' in ../roundcube/plugins/vtrc/vtwsclib/Vtiger/WSClient.php on line 93

function in php file (line 93 ends)

```
function hasError($result) {
        if(isset($result[success]) && $result[success] === true) {
            $this->_lasterror = false;
            return false;
        }
        $this->_lasterror = $result[error];
        return true;
```

Comment: I guess you need to add quotes, so the array access would look like `$result['error']` or `$result['success']`

Comment: If `error` is a string you need to use quotes or double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two IMPORTANT errors!!

**First of all** : You need to use ' OR " to get the value of an Array

```
$value = $array["KEY_HERE"];

Same as
$value = $array['KEY_HERE'];
```

PHP is friendly with quotes =)

---

**Second** : You need to check if "error" Key exists in Array $result like as "success"

```
function hasError($result) {
    if(isset($result["success"]) && $result["success"] === true) {
        ... CODE ...
    }
    if(isset($result["error"])) {
        ... CODE ...
    }
    ... REST OF METHOD ...
}
```

---

**What does it mean "Illegal string offset 'error'?** Exactly that not exists Index 'error' for Array $result. Please be careful, because the script had tried to access in a memory piece that is not declared (initialized - set) for this array. It's dangerous !!

```
$myArray = array();                /** Empty array **/
$myArray["error"] = "";            /** set index "error" with "" value **/

echo isset($myArray["error"]);     /** echo TRUE **/
echo isset($myArray["success"]);   /** echo FALSE **/
echo $myArray["success"];          /** throw exception "Illegal string offset 'success' ..." because not set in Array **/
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to get index of associative array with string offset add `"` or `'` for offset. change your function to

```
function hasError($result) {
        if(isset($result["success"]) && $result["success"] === true) {
            $this->_lasterror = false;
            return false;
        }
        $this->_lasterror = $result["error"];
        return true;
```